# What's the smarter way to sum multiple data with same date and repeat for a month?

Tags: sql, select, spreadsheet

SO I have a few data with same date on google spreadsheet

```
Date             Number 
01/03/2021       3000
01/03/2021       2000
01/03/2021       1000
02/03/2021       500
05/03/2021       700
```

I would like to sum the number and sort it to the 01/03/2021 cell in another sheet
but how to sum all data in March without manually doing it for each day?

```
Date          Number
01/03/2021    6000
02/03/2021    500
05/03/2021    700
```

thanks!!!

Comment: Are you using MS Access, and if not, what is your version of SQL?

Comment: `=QUERY(Sheet1!A2:B6,"select A, sum(B) group by A")` https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/36103/how-to-group-data-in-a-google-spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

A basic `GROUP BY` query should yield the result you want:

```sql
SELECT Date, SUM(Number) AS Number
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Date;
```